# Integrating Youtube Data API v3 in android

Tags: android, api, youtube, google-api, google-signin

I am trying to access users YouTube private data like subscriptions which require OAuth authentication. I have tried 2 approaches so far.

1.Using `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()` method. But it's deprecated and using this function only access token can be acquired which expires after 1 hour. I have no idea how to retrieve refresh token using this method.

2.According to this [article](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/05/improving-security-and-user-experience.html) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35154509/android-how-to-get-refresh-token-by-google-sign-in-api) we should avoid use of getToken method because of security and UX problems. So I tried using `Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API`. According to the documentation, we need to use `GoogleSignInOptions`. So I used it and using `requestScopes()` i added the Youtube scope. Also I used `requestserverauthcode()` to get the exchange code, using which access and refresh token can be acquired. Now here's my problem, we need to use `GoogleApiClient` with `addApi()`. The available set of API's doesn't have a Youtube API listed to put it in `addApi()`. So there is no way  I can get access to access tokens / refresh token.

Can anyone help me out?

EDIT:

I solved it. I used getToken approach to get tokens. Whenever a 401 authorization error occurs, we need to call `getToken` method returns a new token.